# How to find outliers in R comparing text to a numerical value?

Tags: r

I am trying to learn R, and finding it difficult to find precisely what I am looking for.  There are tons of libraries.

I have a sample data set of data, of 150k first and last names and their salaries.

For fun, I would like to see if any first or last names are associated with significantly higher or lower pay.

```
,"FirstName","LastName","BasePay"
1,"NATHANIEL","FORD","167411.18"
2,"GARY","JIMENEZ","155966.02"
3,"ALBERT","PARDINI","212739.13"
```

I have tried using : `library("arulesViz")` and `rules <- apriori(data)`

But it seems to try to find correlation to precise salary numbers, not that the salary is relatively high or low.

Any help on this problem to get me started would be really appreciated!

Regards, Steven

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is more about statistics and not really a specific programming question. Perhaps it's better to ask this on [Cross Validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a perfectly legitimate question.
I would use the package dplyr. You can then use the 'group_by' and 'summarise' functions. In your case group_by(FirstName) and then choose any kind of statistic, i.e. mean or median of salary as a measure of bias.